# Replace css class using javascipt not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to change the class of the element when i click on an icon

1. i click
2. if the curent class is `'text_area_box'` then remove it and add the `'text_area_box_active'`
3. i tested the `if(element.classList.contains('text_area_box'))` and got `true` as a result so that means **the condition work perfectly**... js code is bellow.
4. Now replacing the classes should work **but there is no result on the html page**

The problem is on the javascript code  where the condition work perfectly but the page does not change

here is my code:

```js
function update_function() {
var element = document.getElementById("text_area_box");

if(element.classList.contains('text_area_box'))  /*the condition works perfectly*/
 {

   element.classList.remove('text_area_box');
   element.classList.add('text_area_box_active');
   
 }
else{

   element.classList.remove('text_area_box_active');
   element.classList.add('text_area_box');
}
 
}
```

```css
.text_area_box_active{
    position: relative;
  }
  .text_area_box {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<div class="swiper-slide">
    <i class="fa-regular fa-pen-to-square" id="update_pen"  onclick="update_function()"></i> <--- the button
    <div class="services-item mb-40 elementor-repeater-item-78d8e80" id="swiper-slide-one">
        <div class="services-item__content">
            <div class="text_area_box" id="text_area_box"> <--- the class to change
                <input type="text" name="" required="">
                <label>Titre</label>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

sorry if there is any lack of explanation.

Comment: @SebastianSimon its update_function() i will update it, it is correct on the code just miss typed here.

Comment: Have you looked at the toggle function?

Comment: @AHaworth no i didn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working fine, your button was empty, so no click to call the function.

```js
  function update_function() {
    var element = document.getElementById("text_area_box");
    
    if(element.classList.contains('text_area_box'))  /*the condition works perfectly*/
     {
    
       element.classList.remove('text_area_box');
       element.classList.add('text_area_box_active');
       
     }
    else{
    
       element.classList.remove('text_area_box_active');
       element.classList.add('text_area_box');
    }
     
    }
```

```css
.text_area_box_active{
        position: relative;
      }
      .text_area_box {
        position: relative;
        display: none;
        font-size: xx-large;
        color: red;
      }
```

```html
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <i class="fa-regular fa-pen-to-square" id="update_pen"  onclick="update_function()">button</i> <--- the button
        <div class="services-item mb-40 elementor-repeater-item-78d8e80" id="swiper-slide-one">
            <div class="services-item__content">
                <div class="text_area_box" id="text_area_box"> <--- the class to change
                    <input type="text" name="" required="">
                    <label>Titre</label>
                </div>        
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: i switched **document.getElementById("text_area_box")** by document.querySelector("...") and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I actualy was doing it all correctly but one small thing that i did not understend yet was causing the problem:

-When i changed `document.getElementById('')` to `document.querySelector('')` it worked fine.

javascript:

```
  function update_function() {
    var element = document.querySelector(".text_area_box"); // instead of getElementById
    
    if(element.classList.contains('text_area_box'))  /*the condition works perfectly*/
     {
    
       element.classList.remove('text_area_box');
       element.classList.add('text_area_box_active');
       
     }
    else{
    
       element.classList.remove('text_area_box_active');
       element.classList.add('text_area_box');
    }
     
    }
```

```
.text_area_box_active{
    position: relative;
  }
  .text_area_box {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
  }
```

```
<div class="swiper-slide">
    <i class="fa-regular fa-pen-to-square" id="update_pen"  onclick="update_function()"></i> <--- the button
    <div class="services-item mb-40 elementor-repeater-item-78d8e80" id="swiper-slide-one">
        <div class="services-item__content">
            <div class="text_area_box" id="text_area_box"> <--- the class to change
                <input type="text" name="" required="">
                <label>Titre</label>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show how you use querySelector

Comment: leave a comment for the correct answer to fix his typo